# Geany do not find path to python

Tags: python, windows, geany

I've been using PyCharm for a month but decided to give geany a try.

I've spend hours looking at all the installation and setup tutorials on the web and youtube and even in my book it tells you how to set it up. They all say the same thing and as far as I know, I've done exactly what they said. (I found a question on here by someone with the exact same problem but it was never answered.)

go to Build>Set Build Commands, in the box next to Execute, put in the path to where python is located.

Here is my path

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

I don't know why my python installed in such an unusual place. Everyone else's look like this: `C:\Python35\python`. Is that the problem? When I go into `C:\Users\{username}`, the `AppData` folder is not visible. Is this for security? Is Geany not able to access those folders cause they are invisible?

I'm pretty sure you don't need the `.exe` so I deleted it.

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python "%f"
```

When I hit execute, I can see the command window appear for a split second and then disappear, probably because it tries, but can't find python so closes.

I don't know what the `%f` is but everyone has it anyways.
Before I entered all that into the text box, by default in that text box, there was `.\%e` I don't know what that is all about.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: `%f` is replaced by the filename of the file selected in the editor when the menu item is selected (e.g. `myprogram.py`). `%e` is replaced by the same filename but without the last extension (e.g. `myprogram`)

Comment: Well, I've had no problem with PyCharm until today. I was following along in the book "python crash course" and I had to do a unittest and it didn't work. I actually contacted the author and he told me pycharm handles things differently and told me to add some other code I'd never seen before. I don't like the idea of just adding some code i've never heard of before or seen without a paragraph explaining what it is and what it does. So since that author recommended geany, I decided to try it in geany but I can't get geany to work.

Comment: abccd, if there are any experienced geany users here I'm hoping they can help me solve this problem. It seems like a simple thing to set up but it's not working.

Comment: In Ubuntu, my Execute command is `python3 "%f"`. You might need to add Python to your environment variables in Windows - see https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're question is about `%tags` look at Geany's manual at [Substitutions in commands and working directories](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#substitutions-in-commands-and-working-directories) section:

> The first occurrence of each of the following character sequences in
>   each of the command and working directory fields is substituted by the
>   items specified below before the command is run.
>
> ```
> %d - substituted by the absolute path to the directory of the current file.
> %e - substituted by the name of the current file without the extension or path.
> %f - substituted by the name of the current file without the path.
> %p - if a project is open, substituted by the base path from the project.
> %l - substituted by the line number at the current cursor position.
> ```
>
> *Note*: If the basepath set in the project preferences is not an absolute path, then it is taken as relative to the directory of the
>   project file. This allows a project file stored in the source tree to
>   specify all commands and working directories relative to the tree
>   itself, so that the whole tree including the project file, can be
>   moved and even checked into and out of version control without having
>   to re-configure> the build menu.